# Limit email sending to 1000 emails per day - own smtp - C# - Windows Form Applicaiton

Tags: c#, smtp

In windows Form Application, I am using Mail Definition class to send HTML emails. I got help from this post 
[Generating HTML email body in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886728/generating-html-email-body-in-c-sharp)

I want to send 1000 emails per day. Do I need to set some SMTP setting or I need to write my own code to handle this.

I am thinking to put all the emails in SQL Server table and then select 1000 per day and then delete the addresses to whom email is sent. My approach is good or bad ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can obviously write your own application to handle this, it's not a major challenge just create a list and take the top 100 each day.

I'm going to assume that you're not simply spamming people and have their permission to contact them. You will also have their email client's spam filters to worry about, in the scheme of bulk email a thousand is not a lot - however each SMTP server builds up a particular reputation based on it's domain and IP address. If you fail these tests you will be delivered into the junk folder (if at all!).

By taking on this work yourself you're likely to have less success than using a 3rd party [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com) for example. Companies like this spend a long time nurturing their sender reputation and screening their clients (so they don't allow spammers to use their servers). Take a look at my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504911/sending-email-with-php-and-ensuring-it-doesnt-get-blocked/9505137#9505137) to see some of the issues you'll face.