# Email going straight to Junk

Tags: c#, html, vb.net, windows-server-2008

I have the following code in vb.net running on a VPS and every time i send a email it goes straight to peoples junk box. any help?

```
 Dim email As MailMessage
            email = New MailMessage
            email.From = New MailAddress("Email@address", "Name")
            email.To.Add(New MailAddress(Toemail))
            email.Subject = subject
            email.Body = HTMLstr
            email.IsBodyHtml = True

            Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
            SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = False
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = False
            SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("Email@Address", "Password")
            SmtpServer.Port = 25
            SmtpServer.Host = "localhost"
            SmtpServer.Send(email)
            SmtpServer.Dispose()
```

Comment: Perhaps the content really is junk. If you're sending emails successfully this isn't a programming problem. Problems with spam filters are off-topic for [so]

Comment: just for the record, i'm not spamming people, i'm reporting on stuff they request

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending Email with PHP and ensuring it doesn't get blocked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504911/sending-email-with-php-and-ensuring-it-doesnt-get-blocked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spam filters depend on the content of the email as opposed to the programming that goes behind sending the email:

> Spam filters look at a long list of criteria to decide whether your
>   email is junk. They might look for spammy phrases like “CLICK HERE!”
>   or “FREE! BUY NOW!” They’ll assign points every time they see one of
>   those phrases. Certain criteria get more points than others. Here’s a
>   sample of criteria from SpamAssassin
>
> Talks about lots of money (.193 points) Describes some sort of
>   breakthrough (.232 points) Looks like mortgage pitch (.297 points)
>   Contains urgent matter (.288 points) Money back guarantee (2.051
>   points) If your campaign’s total “spam score” exceeds a certain
>   threshold, then your email goes to the junk folder. You’re probably
>   thinking, “What’s the threshold I need to stay under?” Sorry, but the
>   number is different for every server.
>
> As for that list of “spammy” criteria, it’s constantly growing and
>   adapting, because spam filters learn more about junk every time
>   someone clicks the spam button in their email program.
>
> Spam filters even sync up with each other to share what they’ve
>   learned. Although there's no magic formula, we can help you avoid
>   common mistakes that send newsletters to junk folders.
>
> Avoid these common mistakes
>
> These are the most common mistakes we see new email marketers make,
>   which result in accidental spam filtering:
>
> Using spammy phrases, like “Click here!” or “Once in a lifetime
>   opportunity!” Going crazy with exclamation points!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! USING
>   ALL CAPS, WHICH IS LIKE SCREAMING AT THE TOP OF YOUR LUNGS VIA EMAIL
>   (especially in the subject line) Coloring fonts bright red or green
>   Coding sloppy HTML, usually from converting a Microsoft Word file to
>   HTML Creating an HTML email that’s nothing but one big image, with
>   little or no text (since spam filters can’t read images, they assume
>   you’re a spammer that’s trying to trick them) Using the word “test” in
>   the subject line (agencies run into this when sending drafts to
>   clients for approval) Sending a test to multiple recipients within the
>   same company (that company’s email firewall can only assume it’s a
>   spam attack) Designing HTML email in Word and exporting the code to
>   HTML (That code is sloppy, and spam filters hate it.)

*Source: [MailChimp: How to Avoid Spam Filters](http://mailchimp.com/resources/guides/how-to-avoid-spam-filters/html/)*

Comment: I do have a few hyperlinks that i could re-word. thanks for the tips