# PHP contact form giving error

Tags: php, html

My basic contact form is giving me the error "error during sending mail". Of course, the code below is very simple and has no protection against spammers or SQL injection, but my main concern at the moment is getting the message to send.

Thanks in advance for any help given, despite the simplicity of the question.

HTML:

```
<form action="sendmail.php" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Name" size="20" maxlength="40" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Email" size="20" maxlength="60" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Message:</td>
            <td><textarea  name="Message" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div align="left">
        <input name="submit" type="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

sendmail.php PHP:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {

        $name = $_POST['Name'];
        $email = $_POST['Email'];
        $message = $_POST['Message'];
        $from = 'From: CWON Australia';
        $to = "......@hotmail.com";
        $subject = "CWON Message";

        $content = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

        if(mail ($to, $subject, $content, $from)) {
            echo "mail has been sent";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "error during sending mail";
        }       
    }
?>
```

Comment: probably your mail server isn't working `mail()`

Comment: Look in your error_log and tell us your error/warning/notice

Comment: @AdamAzad Can you expand on that for me? How would I solve an issue with mail(), if there is one?

Comment: do you have mail server configured and working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is functional, and I assume you're getting the "mail has been sent" response.

If you aren't, then you'll first want to check your php.ini for the correct sendmail path (this I believe is the default):

sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

If sendmail path is good, do you see your email in mail logs? I'd also test by mailing your user account on the server itself.

It's more likely that you're getting owned by a spam filter, especially if you're emailing to an "@hotmail.com" address.

See [this SO question for some guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504911/sending-email-with-php-and-ensuring-it-doesnt-get-blocked)

Comment: I receive the "error during sending mail" message unfortunately. I'm stumped.

Comment: ini_set('display_errors',1) to help, sendmail/path is probably not configured properly on the server.

Comment: Thank you, you've given me a lot to research. I'll read more on all of this and see if I can fix it.

Comment: Good luck. The PHP is totally fine, so it's something with your MTA config on the server. Check webserver logs too, it could be a simple permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `mail()` function is not very reliable in php and it is hard to configure... So I recommend you use the **PHPMailer** to send your mails...
You can read all about how to send mail using PHPMailer in here : [PHPMailer GitHUB](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)